# Why isn't NFS over SSH transparent to NFS?

Tags: centos7, ssh-tunnel, nfs4

NFS over LAN seems to work as expected - one downloads nfs-utils rpm, makes a share, modifies ownership and SEL, allows nfs in firewalld, launches nfs-server daemon, and everything is good to go.
Wanting to access files over the internet, I setup an SSH tunnel, as a quick alternative to implementing and maintaining kerberos, however nothing is working as exptected.

Given the following topology:
NFS-server (192.168.1.2) - Gateway (LAN 192.168.1.1, WAN 1.2.3.4) - Internet - Home

I've tried setting up SSH tunnel directly to NFS server:
`home: ssh -fNv -L 2049:localhost:2049 NFS-server`

and via Gateway:
`home: ssh -fNv -L 2049:192.168.2:2049 Gateway`

Ultimately, when mounting either option on home pc,
`home: mount -o port=2049 -t nfs localhost:/var/nfsshare /mnt`
I get the same response - `requested NFS version or transport protocol is not supported`

I've been reading up peoples experience with NFS over SSH and it seems to range greatly, from people just getting it to [work](https://gist.github.com/proudlygeek/5721498) , to [having to configure services never mentioned with plain NFS](https://www.linuxjournal.com/content/encrypting-nfsv4-stunnel-tls) - i.e. rpcbind, nfs-lock, nfs-idmap.

So my question is, should NFS with SSH 'just work', or does SSH forwarding introduce something that NFS can't handle natively?

Comment: This requires NFSv4 at minimum. You didn't specify what NFS version you are using on both ends. You probably also have to specify TCP explicitly.

Comment: Instead of using `localhost` try using the IP the service is normally connected from.  `ssh -fNv -L 2049:192.168.1.2:2049 NFS-server`

Comment: @MichaelHampton, @ivanivan - thanks for the help, turns out what was missing was `insecure` in the exports option. Other than that, everything is behaving as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out what was missing was `insecure` in the exports option. Other than that, everything is behaving as expected

Comment: Can you share your `/etc/exports`? I'm trying something similar, and getting `mount.nfs4: access denied by server while mounting localhost:/media`, even though I have specified `insecure` in my `/etc/exports`: `/media 127.0.0.1(ro,no_subtree_check,insecure,no_root_squash,sync)`